# How to import arrays of data into Simulink

Tags: matlab, import, simulink

I want to import several arrays of data into Simulink so that I can cycle through each of those arrays, operating on one column at a time, and choosing a different array at random intervals. (So let's say I start cycling through the columns of array 1 for 1 second, then I'll move over to array 2, then array 3 and back to array 1). 
I can't use From File blocks because each column then has a specific timestamp associated to it, so I can neither cycle, nor start the simulation selecting a different array each time.

Is there a solution to this problem in Simulink?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a MATLAB Function Block.  Have your array input to it as a Parameter, which means it'll pick the whole array up from the MATLAB Workspace during model initialization.

Depending on how you want to index into the matrix -- you haven't given enough information to determine this -- you could either,

1. have 2 signals input to the MATLAB Function block that represent a row index and column index.  You'd then have logic in the model that specifies these signal/index values.
2. have 2 persistent variables within the MATLAB Function block that define the row and column indices.  Have logic in the block that specify how these variables change each time step.

Comment: Oh yeah nice. Thanks a lot for your help!  So I made a constant block and call the array to it using its variable name. But this means that I have to always open the data files in Matlab, then run the simulation. Is there no way to import the data into Simulink from a file directly without calling it into the workspace first?

Comment: You can load a .mat file directly, using the From File block, because it has a standard format.  For a generic file, that could have a generic format, it's unrealistic to assume that a generic block is going to be able to load it.  However, it's trivial to write a custom block (s-function, MATLAB Function, or even Interpreted MATLAB Function) to read a specific file, with a specific format, when the simulation initializes.   Alternatively you can use the model's StartFcn (or similar) to do it automatically for you (once you're written the code).

Comment: Great thanks, I'll have a look at those options, thanks!